# CMC (RFC 5272) compatible CA server

Tags: encryption, cryptography, tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I need a CA server or any tool that supports Certificate Management over CMS (CMC) format, described in RFC 5272 (RFC 2797). I need a possibility to generate different Full PKI requests and responses to test a custom CMC implementation with.

I know that Microsoft's Enterprise PKI supports it but its not flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, CMC is supported by the [Red Hat Certificate System](http://www.redhat.com/certificate_system/) (see the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/8.1/html/Command-Line_Tools_Guide/index.html) for the command-line tools `CMCRequest`, `CMCEnroll`, `CMCResponse` and `CMCRevoke`); and it seems to be also supported by its open-source counterpart, the [Dogtag Certificate System](http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page). I am not completely savvy on the relationships between the two projects, but they are probably quite close. For instance, when someone asked how to test CMC with Dogtag, he was responded to with [pointers to the Red Hat CS documentation](https://www.redhat.com/archives/pki-users/2011-December/msg00001.html).

I also found some very recent [messages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ejbca/forums/forum/132019/topic/5492097) about people working on CMC support for [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/) (but nothing complete yet).